# Why strcasestr or (strstr) function outputs (null)?

Tags: c, cs50, strstr

here is the code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

string alphabet = "abdcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
string text = "world";
string ciphertext = "";

for(int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++)
{
     ciphertext = strstr(alphabet, &text[i]);
     printf("%s \n", ciphertext);
}
```

It outputs the following result:

```
(null) 
(null) 
(null) 
(null) 
dcefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

So it looks like strstr() works only for the last character, in this case "d".
Why it does not work for prior characters?
strcasestr() has the same behavior

Comment: `strstr` returns a pointer to the matching substring, or `NULL`, as described on man page. Of these strings `"world"` `"orld"` `"rld"` `"ld"` and `"d"` only the last is a substring of `alphabet `.

Comment: Aside there is a typo in the sequence of `alphabet` letters.

Comment: What output do you expect? BTW: don't type a hardcoded alphabet, instead let your program construct it. The computer won't get it wrong like you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want to find **character** in the string, not string in the string, you need to use `strchr` function:

```
for(size_t i = 0; text[i]; i++)
{
     ciphertext = strchr(alphabet, text[i]);
     printf("%s \n", ciphertext);
}
```

1. Use the correct type for indexes (`size_t`)
2. You do not have to call `strlen` on every iteration. It is enough to check if you did not reach the null terminating character.

Answer (score 2):

`strstr` looks for a string in another string. In C, a string is an array of characters, terminated by a NUL character. The first time through your loop, you are calling `strstr` with a pointer to the `w` in `world`, so the string you are telling it to search for is `world`, which does not appear in your alphabet. Then the loop goes on to search for `orld`, `rld`, etc, none of which occur in the alphabet string, until it eventually gets to just `d`, which it finds.